# how to deal with new objects in unit-of-work pattern

Tags: unit-of-work

I am implementing Unit-of-Work pattern, but I am confused with the new objects. In my UoW implementation, I am keeping the objects record in arrays whit index `ClassName.ID` but when a new object is created it has no ID (until its saved into DB), so how should I keep track of such objects in UoW?

Comment: Can you use flags to indicate the object state: `IsNew`, `IsDirty`, `IsDeleted`? You could have your objects inherit from a base class and define the flags in the base class.

Comment: I already have these flags, but without the proper ID, how can I keep track of the model? I am using the `ClassName.ID` index, so I can easily check if a particular object already exists? If I stop using this index and move to numeric index, then I will have to loop through all the objects in the array to check if a particular object exists or not, which is not a good approach.

Comment: Is this `ClassName.ID` a property on your model class? Can you have a randomly generated string only for new objects and check the state using the `IsNew` flag? The DB code will generate proper IDs, but you will need to synchronize your list (update the random strings with the proper IDs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed the suggestion by [dradu] and implemented it accordingly. So for new items I am using a `tempID` which is a unique string starting with underscore, so even if the string contains all numerics, I can still easily identify the `tempID`. Before saving each new item, I get its `tempID` and if its saved successfully, I remove objects from the UoW containing the key `ClassName.tempID`, and add the same item again. As this time the item has proper `ID`, so its added in the UoW with `ClassName.ID` and later can easily be tracked.